# Chai Framework API does not recommend negation

Tags: javascript, node.js, chai

So , I was going through the API guide for the Chai framework and I find that each and every API has an aside that "However it is best to verify that the function returns the exact output , else it may lead to unexpected results"

In many cases, negation can be used to verify that a certain array or object contains or does not contain a value/ key-value pair. For example:

```
expect(1).to.not.be.oneOf([2, 3, 4]);// Not Recommended
```

Why is this not recommended , the guide does not do a good job of explaining this?

The reason why,could seem trivial and obvious to some , but I would appreciate it if someone could shed some light on this . Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example that I came up with: say that you have a somewhat naive function that, given a color, will return a fruit of that color:

```
function fruitByColor(color) {
  return {
    red    : 'strawberry',
    green  : 'apple',
    purple : 'grape',
  }[color];
}
```

And let's say that you're using this assertion:

```
expect(fruitByColor('red')).to.not.be.oneOf([ 'apple', 'grape' ]);
```

This works as expected, because the color *"red"* returns *"strawberry"*.

However, let's use another assertion, this time for an undefined color:

```
expect(fruitByColor('yellow')).to.not.be.oneOf([ 'apple', 'grape' ]);
```

This still passes the test. Technically, the assertion is true, but you lose the distinction between passing an existing color (that returns a valid result) and an undefined color.

Comment: So this seems issue seems subjective to me , if the tester has access to the code then he should be  okay with a test such as this :                 
expect(fruitByColor('yellow')).to.not.be.oneOf([ 'apple', 'grape' ]);   Else he must steer clear of writing such tests as it could lead to ambiguous results . Is that what your trying to convey ?

Comment: It _is_ subjective, and I can think if cases where `.not.oneOf()` makes perfect sense. However, what the documentation is trying to say (I think) is that _if_ you can check for a specific outcome, you should do so, instead of inversely checking for all possible incorrect outcomes.